# GAMens package for one predictor case

Tags: r

I am trying to use the GAMens package for a 'one dimensional dataset' (one predictor and one response) for a very simple artificial dataset:

```
library(GAMens)
trainingdata <- read.table("D:/data.txt", header = TRUE, sep="\t")
trainingdata.GAMrsm <- GAMens(class~., trainingdata, 1,  autoform=TRUE, iter=10, rsm=FALSE)
```

Unfortunately I get:

Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , as.character(formula[[2]])) : 
  undefined columns selected

Maybe I am missing something but is it should be possible to get this to work for the one dimensional case ('dimensions' greater one work fine). Thanks.

EDIT:

This is how the artificial data is generated:

```
n.site <- 150

    X1<- sort(runif(n = n.site, min = -1, max =1))

    xb <- 0.0 + 3.0*X1 

    occ.prob <- 1/(1+exp(-xb))

    true.presence <- rbinom(n = n.site, size = 1, prob = occ.prob)

    data <- data.frame(X1, true.presence)

    write.matrix(data, file = "data.txt", sep = "\t")
```

Alternatively you can download the data here:

[Data](http://www.zoonosis.ac.uk:8080/download/attachments/17/data.txt)

Comment: Can you replicate this fail with a dataset (or synthetic example) we can all get to? The Ionosphere data from mlbench perhaps, as used in the example shown in help(GAMens)? Or some slice of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved in a new version of the package. Please download version 1.1.2 of the GAMens package via the CRAN repository.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Your `data` input has no column named "class", so the formula you are using `class ~ .` is not valid. Granted, the error message is not very helpful...

This seems to work (but slowly, it is still running after 10 minutes):

trainingdata.GAMrsm <- GAMens(true.presence ~ X1, data, 1, autoform=TRUE, iter=10, rsm=FALSE)

Comment: Yeah sorry. I renamed true.presence to class in my local copy of the data (data.txt). I understand that autoform=TRUE but does true.presence ~ X1 not restrict the 'model space'? I would like to use true.presence~. This would work if the one has more than one predictor. Thanks.